# Another datatable inside the main datatable

Tags: r, shiny

IS there a way to get datatable when the user clicks on the row. Basically when the user clicks on any row, the last 4 columns of that specific row should be displayed in a modal (in datatable format)

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput("mydatatable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  mycars = head(mtcars)
  output$mydatatable = DT::renderDataTable(mycars, selection = 'single',  
                                           rownames = FALSE, options = list(dom = 't'))
  
  observeEvent(input$mydatatable_rows_selected,
               {
                 showModal(modalDialog(
                   title = "You have selected a row!",
                   mycars[input$mydatatable_rows_selected,]
                 ))
               })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `renderDataTable` inside `modalDialog`.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput("mydatatable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  mycars = head(mtcars)
  output$mydatatable = DT::renderDataTable(mycars, selection = 'single',  
                                           rownames = FALSE, options = list(dom = 't'))
  
  observeEvent(input$mydatatable_rows_selected,
               {
                 showModal(modalDialog(
                   title = "You have selected a row!",
                   DT::renderDataTable({
                     DT::datatable(mycars[input$mydatatable_rows_selected, (ncol(mycars) - 3):ncol(mycars)])
                     })
                 ))
               })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]